Converting a virtual machine a standalone directory hosted on Ubuntu
A software platform I'm responsible for requires a minimal Ubuntu distribution with software that is partially integrated with the OS and uses TTY terminals. We've typically contained the OS in a virtual machine in vmdk format. The VM has been hosted on a physical Ubuntu machine running VMware Workstation. That physical machine also hosts the standalone portion of the software and a NAS.
If possible, I want to package this to allow hosting the software platform without installing VMware Workstation or some other hypervisor. I've seen descriptions of using QEMU to convert a VM into a directory structure with all the necessary dependencies. The descriptions are a bit light on details. I'm also a novice with QEMU.
I'm looking for confirmation and advice. Can I use QEMU to convert a vmdk to a standalone directory structure (and throw that into a tarball or something)? Such that the OS & software can run from that standalone structure on another Ubuntu machine? Specifically without installing QEMU or some other hypervisor.
I think the command answered here is likely what I need to use Move qcow2 image to physical hard drive
Here's another relevant link I've reviewed
https://community.spiceworks.com/t/self-contained-stand-alone-vms/808997/6

I don't really understand what kind of directory structure you're expecting to get. Are you trying to convert the VM into a Linux container? That's somewhat of the opposite of "standalone virtual machine"...

Edited. I agree, my description was confusing. It is complicated but hopefully it's more clear now

@ChaseSchuette not quite sure what you mean with "standalone", can you elaborate on that? It's a bit confusing that the two links you provided describe pretty opposite things. I think if you could, instead of just describing what you want to get, describe what you want to do (as in: I want to run … on … for …), that might help!

Are you trying to extract the filesystem from the vmdk? If so then you can use vmware-mount  for that. As for whether this will work as a standalone directory, most things will probably work if you run it under docker instead of a VM

It really seems like you want to export your platform as a docker image

Thanks for the comments.
@MarcusMüller If possible, I want to package this to allow hosting the software platform without installing VMware Workstation or some other hypervisor. The links I reference make me believe that may be possible

Description edited

the first link was "how do I set up a complete PC to run what used to be a VM", which probably isn't what you want. The second link is about putting the definition of the VM (how many CPU cores, which CPU, how much RAM, which network interfaces…) and the data storage in a single file that you can exchange. You still need a hypervisor.

So, neither are what you want.

Such that the OS & software can run from that standalone structure on another Ubuntu machine? Specifically without installing QEMU or some other hypervisor. Makes me think of ("boot" mode) systemd-nspawn. (Not saying that it is what you think / want though.)

Thanks @TomYan Lower-level concepts like systemd-nspawn may be what I need to consider. Perhaps I could leverage chroot.
Otherwise, if this proves to be exceedingly complex. I'll stick with what we've been doing. Having non-technical customers install VMware and trying to instruct them on how to deploy a VM. I would much rather get this packaged so customers can more easily deploy the software
